# syntax error in Hive Query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql

[image]

I am trying to answer this question

```
Of  the right-handed    batters who were    born    in  October and died in 
2011,   which   one had the most    hits    in  his career?
```

My attempt to get the query, Please ignore the total, it supposed to for sums for b.hits, dont know how to alias it.

```
SELECT n.id, n.bmonth, n.dyear,n.bats, SUM(b.hits) FROM master n
JOIN (SELECT b.id , b.hits FROM batting GROUP BY id) o
WHERE n.bmonth == 10 AND n.dyear == 2011) x
ON x.id=n.id 
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Incase anyone needs the schema of the two tables used, look below.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/home/hduser/hivetest/answer4' 
SELECT n.id, n.bmonth, n.dyear,n.bats, SUM(b.hits) FROM master n
JOIN (SELECT b.id , b.hits FROM batting GROUP BY id) o
WHERE n.bmonth == 10 AND n.dyear == 2011) x
ON x.id=n.id 
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, although Hive accepts `==`, that doesn't mean you should use it.  The standard SQL equality operator is simply `=`.  There is no reason to use a synonym.

I suspect the problem is several things:

- The lack of `group by`.
- Mis-use of aggregation functions.
- Missing aliases
- SQL query clauses in the correct order
- Unbalanced parentheses

In other words, the query is just a mess.  You need to review the basics of query syntax.  Does this work?

```
SELECT m.id, m.bmonth, m.dyear, m.bats, b.hits as total
FROM master m JOIN
     (SELECT b.id, SUM(b.hits) as hits
      FROM batting b
      GROUP BY id
     ) b
     ON b.id = m.id 
WHERE m.bmonth = 10 AND m.dyear = 2011
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense and the query ran but didn't return any results, also the WHERE b.bmonth is supposed to be m.bmonth right?